# Problem in sorting using Comparator interface

Tags: java, comparator

I have created a ArrayList of HashMap like

```
ArrayList<HashMap<?,?>>  var = new ArrayList<HashMap<?,?>>();
```

My HashMaps contains a String value "name" with key "name".What I want is to sort ArrayList by name so can I do this using Comparator?
Please Help Me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  var = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    Collections.sort(var, new Comparator(){

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            Map map1 = (Map) o1;
            Map map2 = (Map)o2;
            String name1 = (String) map1.get("name");
            String name2 = (String) map2.get("name");
            if(name1 != null){
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
            } else if(name2 != null){
            return name2.compareTo(name1);
            }else{
             return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is  the answer.

Comment: the use of Map (and not Map<T1,T2>) -  without generics is deprecated. also note no null check for map1.get("name"). but besides from it - this will do the trick.

Comment: What i have written is just a template.

Comment: Oh I just realize we can do that. :)

Comment: @amit yes , i did that in the edit. So that anyone can try using the code directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
  String one = (String)((HashMap)o1).get("name");
  String two = (String)((HashMap)o2).get("name");
  return one.compareTo(two);
}
```

I haven't compiled this, so be sure to check its correct.  =)